# Assembly: st r1, r2(r3) -- Isn't this indexed-memory addressing instruction correct?

Tags: assembly

In this Assembly programming code, is the last instruction correct? Having some arguments with someone here...

```
ldi r1, #$0001    ;load $1 in r1 register
ldi r2, #$4000    ;load $4000 in r2 register
ldi r3, #$0000    ;load $0000 into re register

st r1, r2(r3)     ;store value of r1 in memory location r2(r3) = $4000($0000)
```

Isn't the indexed memory addressing instruction correct?

Comment: You forgot to mention what architecture. This looks like avr to me, in which case it isn't correct. Next time consult your architecture manual or try in an assembler.

Comment: If I was all-knowing, I would know what architecture you use without you having to tell me. As it is, I must rely on you, or guess. You might not be aware that there are many different architectures, with their own instruction sets and addressing modes. What's valid for one of those isn't valid in others. For example x86 doesn't even have `st` instruction or r1-r3 registers.

Comment: If you were implementing your own architecture then **you could decide** if it's going to be valid or not and what it will do. How could we tell? Anyway, I have answered your question: for avr architecture, which does have `st` instruction, that form is not valid. If you are not happy with this answer, you need to provide more details.

Comment: you need to specify the architecture if you want to ask a question here.  folks here have various levels of expertise on likely only one or a few architectures but not all architectures.   fewer folks know lots of architectures, but even there it is just the right thing to do to indicate that.  Just as if you were asking an application programming question to specify the operating system at least and/or compiler...

Comment: As a tip, insulting those trying to help you is not the best way to get a good answer. I've removed those comments of yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if you use st r1, M1 then value of r1 will be stored into the memory location M1.

And in case of st r1, (r3) value of r1 stored into memory of r3

here you have st r1, r2(r3) so value of r1 will be stored into memory of (r2+r3)

Correct me if I am wrong.